# virtualbox vm can not access from outside

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, bridge

I installed a vbox in ubuntu 18.04, and used bridged network by adding parameters:

`--bridgeadapter2 eno1 --nicpromisc2 allow-all`

Everything goes fine, vm can ping outside, and host can ping vm, but outside can not ping vm:
(outside in the same subnet can ping vm, for example: 10.124.214.x can ping vm)

```
# 10.124.214.116 is vm, 10.124.214.4 is host, 10.124.12.103 is outside IP
# From host to vm
traceroute 10.124.214.116
traceroute to 10.124.214.116 (10.124.214.116), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.124.214.116 (10.124.214.116)  0.232 ms  0.197 ms  0.191 ms
# From vm to outside
ping 10.124.12.103
PING 10.124.12.103 (10.124.12.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.124.12.103: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.38 ms
```

The tricky thing is vbox interface does not like normal linux tun/tap interface, I can see interface in  VM, but there is nothing I can operate from host, and there is no bridge on the host.

Is there any API I can trouble shooting vbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers code farmer

You are right about bridge. Thing here is that your VM is currently behind NAT created by virtual box (see different subnets you mentioned)

What you can do here is to create new bridge on host machine (good instructions [HERE](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configuring-bridging-in-debian-linux/))

Using this setup you will have to change networking setting slightly:

```
                                     VM Host
                                     +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
                                     |                                       -> VM A (10.124.214.5/24) |
Outside network (10.124.214.0/24) -> | eno1 (no IP) -> br0 (10.124.214.4/24) -> VM B (10.124.214.6/24) |
                                     |                                       -> VM C (10.124.214.7/24) |
                                     +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then you can assign your VM to `br0`. Depends on your outside network setting you might need to set static IP to your VM

Comment: Actually, I already tried this before, but it does not work. I will try to use a standard ubuntu vm instead, thanks. The issue is vm IP can not used outside host, use traceroute, I can see vm interface works as in the one bridge. Maybe I need to let vbox to broadcast vm IP to outside network, or maybe outside network blocked this traffic...

Comment: Thanks for your support, I think I found the issue existed in that vm. I tried a standard ubuntu VM bridge with host's eno1, it can access from outside network.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the root cause:
There are two interfaces in my VM:
First one is NAT, second one is bridge. By default, vbox set the NAT interface as the default route, when I send out packets, it use NAT interface. But HOST and VM are in the same subnet, when connect to HOST, it use the bridge interface. When I need to access this bridged interface from outside, I need to add another entry of default route by ip route command:

```
sudo ip route add default via 10.124.214.116
```